# how to archive all tables from mysql to sqlite in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, archive

Is there an automated way in rails 3 to archive all the data in my production db (MySQL) into another database (sqlite3)?

Background: I want to save away all of last years data that we don't need quick access to, and then clear out the database so its fresh and will only hold the data of an upcoming project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the taps gem.  Also take a look at the recent railscasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

That episode shows how to use taps to move data between databases.

Comment: I'm going to go the taps route. Thanks for the pointer and I'll try to remember to report back how it went when finished.

Comment: It worked! :) Only three commands and all my data was archived (1. gem install taps; 2. taps server mysql2://db_user:user_password@myurl.com/my_db httpuser httppassword; 3. taps pull sqlite:///path/to/db.sqlite3 http://httpuser:httppassword@localhost:5000) My only complaint is that taps documentation is a little thin and I had quite a bit of trial and error before getting the taps commands right.

Answer (score 0):

Converting data from mysql to sqlite might corrupt some data. If you really want to archive your database I suggest using mysqldump.

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> database_name > database_dump.sql
```

If your db schema is simple enough to be exported in sqlite, here is a script to convert your dump in an sqlite db: https://gist.github.com/943776